# Pandas: process cell dependencies

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, r-factor

I'm new to Pandas so please bear with me; I have a dataframe A:

```
   one  two three
0    1    5     9
1    2    6    10
2    3    7    11
3    4    8    12
```

And a dataframe B, which represents relationships between columns in A:

```
      one two  # these get mutated in place
three   1   1
one     0   0
```

I need to use this to multiply values in-place with values in other columns. The output should be:

```
   one  two three
0    9   45     9
1    20  60    10
2    33  77    11
3    48  96    12
```

So in this case I have made the adjustments for each row:

```
one *= three
two *= three
```

Is there an efficient way to use this with Pandas / Numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#column-selection-addition-deletion)

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]: 
   one  two  three
0    1    5      9   
1    2    6     10  
2    3    7     11  
3    4    8     12  

In [38]: df['one'] *= df['three']

In [39]: df['two'] *= df['three']

In [40]: df
Out[40]: 
   one  two  three
0    9   45      9   
1   20   60     10  
2   33   77     11  
3   48   96     12
```

Comment: This is great, though I suppose I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't require a loop in Python in the case that I didn't know the length of my dependency matrix ahead of time. Is this worth shooting for?

Comment: Does the order matter? What if all the values in your dataframe B are all 1?